# didUpdateLocations never called

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to get the user's location. To do so I have set the following property in the info.plist :

[image]

I have also added the following code in my viewDidLoad method as well as the function below. The problem is that the `locationManager(manager, didUpdate....)` function never gets called, I also never get prompted for permission to access location, even though I have removed and installed the app again. I am testing this on my iPad, not on the simulator. The didFailWithError function never gets called either.

```
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("UPDATING")
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    let latitude = locValue.latitude
    let longitude = locValue.longitude
    latitudeText = "\(latitude)"
    longitudeText = "\(longitude)"
    if let a = latitudeText, b = longitudeText {
        print(a)
        print(b)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        if (userAlreadyExist()) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueWhenLoggedIn", sender: self)
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showCamera", sender: self)
                // self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTabBarController", sender: self)
            })

        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueWhenLoggedOut", sender: self)
            })
        }
    }


}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

EDIT :

I have added the following snippet of code :

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        print("yes")
    }
    else {
        print("no")
    }
```

it returns yes. I have also checked on my device, locationServices are enabled, the app is listed there, however all the other apps have "While Using", "Never" or "Always" written next to them, mine doesn't have anything written.

Comment: can you check if you are using a real device?

Comment: What do you mean? I stated in the question I'm testing this on my iPad

Comment: You are right sorry for my stupid comment

Comment: Can you verify that location services are enabled on your device settings? Do the settings on your app show options for location?

Comment: @DannyBravo please check the edit

Comment: Ok, hmmm... You must have text in the NSLocationWhenInUseDescription key of your plist, an empty string won't do. If that doesn't work try restarting Xcode, I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. What's the OS version you're running on?

Comment: Yeah i did, it's not an empty string. I'm running on iOS 9.3.2 on an ipad2 wifi

Comment: @mankee: Nope, sorry dude, I'm clueless.

Comment: When you use the app for the first time, the `self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization` should prompt the user to allow location updates for your app. Did the prompt ever appear?

Comment: No it hasn't appeared

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but can you verify you actually initialized the `locationManager`? If the prompt is not appearing it might be a safe no-op from calling a method (sending a message) to a `nil` object

Comment: I have this line 'let locationManager = CLLocationManager()' right above my viewDidLoad method

Comment: Double check that the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` is actually executed (in viewDidLoad, for example) and run on the main thread. Another thing is that you should use the delegates like `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` to run `startUpdatingLocation`, because `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` is asynchronous.

Comment: @MirekE I tried implementing bobbys  answer, his code always goes into the "default" part of the switch statement... it makes use of what you said with using the `didChangeAuthorisationStatus` to run `startUpdatingLocation`

Comment: It goes to default because it does not check for `.NotDetermined`. This is what is returned if the user did not allow/deny location services in the app yet.

Comment: @MirekE why do you think the prompt doesn't show prompting the user to accept/deny location services for the app

Comment: Possibilities: you don't actually call it, you don't call it from the main thread, there is some problem with the settings in your plist...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

where do you start the location update ? for example:

```
//location manager
    lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        var _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        _locationManager.delegate = self
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        _locationManager.activityType = . automotiveNavigation
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0  // Movement threshold for new events
        _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true // allow in background

        return _locationManager
    }()


    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() // start location manager

            }
```

here is a working conroller code:
also important to to set up Custom iOS Target Properties.

Add these two lines to the Info.plist:

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  LocationTest2


import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //location manager
    lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        var _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        _locationManager.delegate = self
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        _locationManager.activityType = . automotiveNavigation
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0  // Movement threshold for new events
      //  _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true // allow in background

        return _locationManager
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //allow location use
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        print("did load")
        print(locationManager)

        //get current user location for startup
       // if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       // }
    }
}


// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        for location in locations {

            print("**********************")
            print("Long \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            print("Lati \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
            print("Alt \(location.altitude)")
            print("Sped \(location.speed)")
            print("Accu \(location.horizontalAccuracy)")

            print("**********************")


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I start the locationUpdate in viewDidLoad() (4th line of code in the snippet in the question) I'm not sure what your code has, that mine is missing...

Comment: have also set this, you need both:
 NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription &
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

hier is a nice tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/97944/make-app-like-runkeeper-swift-part-1

Comment: Can you show us your function `viewDidLoad` to see where you are starting your LocationManager. Don't forget that you have to init it before asking for permission.

Comment: Can you try to call `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` before asking for permission ? (Just invert those 2 lignes in your code)

Comment: updated the code, this should work in your controller

Comment: @ppoh71 "Cannot assign value of type LoadingScreen to type CLLocationManagerDelegate" on the line `_locationManager.delegate = self`

Comment: Got this to work using your code, however I had to have both the keys in my info.plist : NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Comment: .AutomotiveNavigation has been changed to .automotiveNavigation in Swift 5.

Answer (score 7):

for me worked:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("locationManager update")
}
```

instead of this

```
private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("locationManager update")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Also make sure you have set the custom location to simulator as by default it will be None ... 
In the simulator go to Debug -> Location-> .

It should also be noted that locationManager:didFailWithError: will run if the location is not set in the simulator, as you'd expect.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `startUpdatingLocation()` inside the `didDetermineState` delegate method

```
  if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }else{
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

//later

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    case .denied:
        //handle denied
        break
    case .notDetermined:
         manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
       break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this or do I need to perform some extra checks? `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, forRegion region: CLRegion) {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }`

Comment: do you have a swift version of that?

Comment: your switch statement always goes into the "default" section

Comment: Yes, it should be `CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined` before the user allows it. This is the situation where you would call the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` because it indicates it was never called/answered.

Comment: @MirekE : If the check is done before, as presented, the NotDetermined case should never happened, but it may be safer to implement it, just in case

Comment: @bobby - it happens until the user answers the prompt and allows/denies location services for the app.

Answer (score 3):

A very subtle cause for this bug in Swift code. Don't define the delegate call didUpdateLocations as private or fileprivate. The location manager won't be able to find or call it if you do.

Good:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
}
```

Bad:

```
fileprivate func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    }
```

Comment: in case CLLocationManager is in framework, you need @objc public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, did...), also it must be on thread that have run loop.

Answer (score 2):

I looked for answers high and low. This is the only thing that worked for me:
Change the func for didUpdateToLocation to:

```
func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!,fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
}
```

Note the **subtle change** of "as _: CLLocationManager", instead of "manager: CLLocationManager".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `startUpdatingLocation` method gets called on the **main** thread, like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using AppDelegate as CLLocationManagerDelegate instead of ViewController like in most examples, this was the code I had

```swift
// AppDelegate.swift

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
  
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ...    
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager?.delegate = self
    return true
  }
}
```

and I was trying to get updates when exit event was called

```swift
// AppDelegate.swift

extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
      return
    }
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    return
  }
}
```

But this didn't work. Instead I had to move the configuration of locationManager to AppDelegate class, and only start the updates in AppDelegate extension.

Like this

```swift
// AppDelegate.swift

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ...    
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager?.delegate = self
    
    /* This was the catch, it needs to be here instead of inside extension */
    self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager?.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    self.locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    /* */
    return true
  }
}
extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
      return
    }
    /* Only do this here */
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    return
  }
}
```

Then it started working, and sending continuous location updates. Also I tested on simulator.