# swift - didUpdateLocations Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on an app that requires getting the user's current coordinates. I was planning on doing this through `CLLocationManager's didUpdateLocations` method. For some reason, `didUpdateLocations` is not being executed. However, it appears that `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` is being called successfully. None of the other possible solutions I've seen on this site have worked for me. I already added `NSLocationAlwaysUsage` to info.plist. Here is the entirety of my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

var region: MKCoordinateRegion!

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!


var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters



self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        print("Updating location now")
        }
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    case .restricted, .denied:
        print("User must enable access in settings")
        break
    }



    if (region == nil){

    }

    else {
    map.setRegion(region!, animated: true)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
}




func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  print("Got location")

  let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
  let lat:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
  let long:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
  let currentPos:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)

  didUpdateRegion(position: currentPos)

  print(lat)
  print(long)

}


func didUpdateRegion(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

  let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.075, 0.075)
  region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: position, span: span)

}

func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
  switch status {
  case .notDetermined:
      // If status has not yet been determied, ask for authorization
      manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
      break
  case .authorizedWhenInUse:
      // If authorized when in use
      manager.startUpdatingLocation()
      break
  case .authorizedAlways:
      // If always authorized
      manager.startUpdatingLocation()
      break
  case .restricted:
      print("User must activate location services in settings")
      break
  case .denied:
      print("User must activate location services in settings")
      break
  default:
      break
  }
}
```

When I run this code on both the simulator and an actual device, I get the notification to allow location tracking. After accepting that, the console displays "Updating location now," but never gets to printing "Got location." Thank you for any light you can shed on this issue, I'm new to app development in general.

EDIT: I added in the entirety of my code instead of just the parts I thought were relevant. Basically, I'm trying to get the region shown on the map to follow the user. I attempt to do this by updating the variable "region" every time the `didUpdateLocations` function fires.

Comment: Check locationServicesEnabled is set to true

Comment: Yes, locationServicesEnabled was set to true.

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the whole code, not the snippets.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: I actually ended up solving the problem myself. Instead of using the updateRegion function, I just updated the map view itself from within the didUpdateLocations function. The only thing I don't understand is that my "map" variable is only recognized when the delegate method is inside my ViewController class. I thought that delegate methods had to go outside the ViewController.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37683701/2050181

Answer (score 1):

Am I getting it right and you only added one key - NSLocationAlwaysUsage?
Try to add both keys to the Info.plist:

- Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
- Privacy - Location Always Usage Description

Also, what happens if you implement this method of protocol?

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
   print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Does it print anything? Sorry, I was going to leave a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I tried adding both keys and adding the error method but no error message was printed to the console.